# Having an issue with the .NET framework I restored but still im facing this error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.424/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
>
> doesn't have a target for '.NETFramework,Version=v6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net60' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

Comment: has it worked before?

Comment: Did you checked that  the`dotnet commands` are recognized accordingly?

Comment: It worked before on windows machine but on mac im facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the [dotnet6 sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks) sdk on your PC:

If you installed it and you are facing this issue, check your .csproj if `<TargetFramework>` is set to `net6.0`

Comment: Yes my <TargetFramework> is set to 6.0 and yes im facing this issue while running the build on mac on windows im facing some other error but not this one.

Comment: which error are you facing on Windows? is it related to this error here?

Comment: Fixed the error by updating the .net framework 6.0 through upgrade assistant and some login functions were deprecated for 6.0 and they were valid for 4.8 so updated that login function.